# XDR data format

Tags: image-processing, soft-question

I have binary XDR data file representing radar data. What is XDR data formatting? What is useful for? How to visualize this binary file? Is there any kind of software that converts this data format in any other?

Comment: Hi @Handshaking, care to share what you're planning to use it for or what your goal is? Because is it wasn't useful to visualize the data, why would we be answering the question?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) says that it is a standard format for serializing data so that it can be shared easily across platforms that might have differing numeric formats or endianness. Whether that's the same XDR as the data that you're holding is anyone's guess. Complex systems like radars often use custom, proprietary formats that you won't find documentation for on the Internet. But, it might be worth giving it a look to see if what you have is actually standard XDR.